# How to justify the height of the row on 100% percent with text

Tags: html, css

I have a container, it has 3 rows. i am applying the height of each row as `30%` and one of the row has the `maring:5%` top and bottom. and all my rows has the text in it.

But i am not getting correct result here. how to measure this? when i measure the height by `%` how to calculate the `text - line-height` with that?

here is the code :

```css
.parent {
  height : 20em;
  position:relative;
}
.userOptions {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
.userOptions .row {
  padding: 15% 0; /*this is 90% */
  background: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:0;
}
.userOptions .row.suplyOption {
  margin: 5% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      
   <div class="userOptions">
  <div class="row designOption">
   Design
  </div>
  <div class="row suplyOption">
   Supply
  </div>
  <div class="row constOption">
   Construction
  </div>
 </div>
   </div>
```

any one help me to understand this?

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying can you be clear.?

Comment: Do you want the height of the row be equal to the text?

Comment: @user2024080 you have given the **.userOptions .row ** selector padding top and bottom with 15% and also given line height that is clashing for your actual result

Comment: @ManishKothari - Do you want the height of the row be equal to the text? Yes

Comment: @ Himesh Aadeshara  yes i agree. this is what the answer i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Remove `line-height:0;` from your code, it is conflicting with your padding.

You can try this for instance:

```
.userOptions .row {
    padding: 0% 0; /*Change padding*/
    background: #808080;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example 1: line-height = 150%

and your font-size is 14px.

So your line-height will be 14 * 150% = 21px.

For example 2: if line-height = 2

and your font-size is 14px.

So your line-height will be 14 * 2 = 28px.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I agree with you. But how to mange here? can you update in to snippet? or show me a live demo